# HQL "Contains" statement howto?

Tags: nhibernate, hql, contains, icriteria

I have an entity that has a string property called Tags. I would like to query this entity based upon if a certain string is located in Tags property.

So for example, I would have a function IList GetEntityByTag(string tag), this would return all Entity's that have the value of tag in their 'Tags' property.

I tried going through the ICriteria approach... Expression.In(PropertyName, Value) but this is the exact opposite. I need something like Expression.In(Value, PropertyName).

Perhaps IQuery would be a better strategy but I have not been able to find any type of HQL statment for Property CONTAINS 'abc'.

Any help or point of direction would be great thanks!

Comment: Here's a link to a great article on expressions, and how to use Criteria: http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery102/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean Expression.Like(PropertyName, Value)?

Comment: Hi Alex, this is similar to Expression.In but it's still the opposite of what I require. I want to know if Value exists in PropertyName. Not if PropertyName exists in Value

Comment: Unless... let's say my property, 'Tags' = a;b;c;d;e. I want to know if 'a' exists in tags. Will Expression.Like("Tags", "a") return true?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know if a tag is a substring in your Tags property, you might want to consider these tips:

- You might want to convert both the string you are searching in and searching for to lowercase first.  Expression.ilike does this for you.  Score.
- To find out if your search term is anywhere in the field, you can set the MatchMode parameter in the ilike function to MatchMode.ANYWHERE.

If, as you commented earlier,

> let's say my property, 'Tags' =
>   a;b;c;d;e. I want to know if 'a'
>   exists in tags. Will
>   Expression.Like("Tags", "a") return
>   true?

If 'a;b;c;d;e' is a string, Expression.ilike( "Tags", "a", MatchMode.ANYWHERE ) will return true.

Comment: how would you go about doing this using IQuery?