# hql get objects where objects' property is "substring" of input value

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, hql

I am running into similar situation as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525900/hql-contains-statement-howto). My pseudo code is

```
string hql = "select ai from AreaInfo as ai where ai.PhoneSegment is substring of :InputPhoneNumber";
```

Using like wouldn't do the trick because what Like is doing is

```
string hql = "select ai from AreaInfo as ai where :InputPhoneNumber is substring of ai.PhoneSegment";
```

So, what is the correct syntax to perform this task? My environment is Castle ActiveRecord on top of NHibernate.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to do something like this:

```
select ai from AreaInfo ai where :InputPhoneNumber like concat('%', ai.PhoneSegment)
```

Is that it?